# How do I align two signals in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have two arrays with the same size:

```
s1 = [112    85    80    88   110   142   168   188   204   206   202   192   180   162   144   123   100    83    72    87   118   147   169   184   191   195   193   185   170   152   132   113    93    87    77    89   112   140   161   179   185   185   183   178   166   152   136   118    96    74];  
s2 = [165   143   116   103    86    93   103   135   166   187   196   203   200   195   184   168   151   131   109    85    73    76    99   131   153   172   180   187   189   188   177   161   143   125   105    91    85    81    92   113   142   162   176   182   181   178   172   161   150   136];
```

How is it possible to shift or align `s1` with `s2`?

For example, here is how the arrays look before alignment:

[image: before alignment]

And after alignment:

[image: after alginment]

Also, how can I get the similarity between the two signals? Is it possible with `xcorr`?

Comment: Yes you could use `xcorr` and find the offset that yields the highest correlation and then apply that shift to your signal with `circshift`

Comment: hi can you help me go through it, i got this values http://imgur.com/a/J9PRh after i typed xcorr(s1,s2)

Comment: If you have a recent version of MATLAB and the Signal Processing Toolbox, use [`alignsignals`](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/alignsignals.html).